# Auto close popup message "open method of workbooks class failed"

Tags: excel, windows

I am trying to convert a batch of excel files into PDF using Doc2PDF software. Sometimes a corrupt excel comes in a batch and throws an error message "_open method of workbooks class failed". Is there any way to disable windows popup in batch file or using .vbs ? As i don't want my automation job to halt until i click close to the error popup

> ***My current batch script :***

```
echo "Starting Dev Filewatcher 2 ....."
@echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\docPrint Pro v5.0
perl C:\Script\Test\xyz.pl -DbgMsgLevel 9 ^
-IncomingDir C:\Script\incoming ^
-ProcessDir C:\Script\process ^
-SuccessDir C:\Script\success ^
-FailDir C:\Script\fail ^
-ExceptionsDir C:\Script\exception ^
-OutgoingDir C:\Script\outgoing ^
-SleepInt 1 ^
-ConvertCmd "doc2pdf.exe -s SilentPrintOffice=1 -b 1 -i"
```

Comment: if you are using a vbs file then this line will make the error not stop the whole code execution, there are better methods to trap the error or make a log of the ones which were not converted, but you need to provide your VBA code for that so for now use: `on error resume next` at the beginning of the vbs code

Comment: @Ibo - IMO that is absolutely **terrible** advice to give to a new coder.  "Instead of fixing the problem, just ignore it!"

Comment: @tushar - You'll need to provide more information in order to convey your issue and what you've tried. You can [edit] your question to add the code that you've tried (please see **how to create a [mcve]**) and perhaps a [cropped] screenshot of the error where it's occurring. Also [here are some posting tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from the site's top user.  There are numerous similar questions on this site & others, have you done some research and tried some variations of your code?

Comment: @ashleedawg - Provided batch file which i have currently to execute the program, this batch basically monitors incoming directory and if any excel file is dropped in that folder it converts in the pdf file. But when a corrupt excel is dropped i get the error dialog box.

Comment: @ashleedawg that was what he needed and I explained the drawback of the method and he needs to go and explore it himself, it was only a clue. I told him there are better methods and he needs to share his code, it is up to him to take the risk or put more efforts to create a better code